# How to build a two systems integration with messaging

Tags: integration, nservicebus, rabbitmq, esb

I need to integrate two different systems at a customers site and don't know if messaging solutions like NServiceBus or RabbitMQ are the right way to go. To be honest, I haven't fully understood what problem they are actually trying to solve...

System 1 is an accounting system.
System 2 is a manufactoring system.

Both use SQL server but they are physically seperated and I can't use something like SSIS. The (simplified) goal is that a new order created in System 1 would create an equivalent order in System 2. After the order has been in created in System 2, I need to write back a reference number of System 2 back into System 1.

I've talked to both vendors of these systems. I can create create a SQL trigger in System 1's database in their 'orders' table. In order to create the order in system 2 I can write to a 'importorders' table in their database. System 2 will have a task scheduled every 1-2 minutes that creates the new orders in their system and write back the reference number into the row. Of course, I can have a trigger on this table ('importorders') as well.

What would be a good solution to do the integration in between?

I have heard about NServiceBus and RabbitMQ, but I don't know if they are the right tool to use for this kind of problem?

Comment: Can the reference number be something generated that gets pushed into System2?  This would avoid the hand shaking process.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It definitely needs to be created inside System2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the ability to modify the code of either system and have to integrate at the level of SQL, then messaging probably isn't going to be the best choice for you.

Comment: Thanks Udi, no I can't modify the code of either system and have to do it at SQL leve. What keyword comes to your mind instead of messaging in this case? Thanks